# Symfony2: Use @Route and dependency injection in __construct() together

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I register Symfony2 controllers as a services and I use dependency injection by constructor. Controllers isn't child of main Controller class. When I use routing by routing.yml, that's OK, but when I want use @Route annotation, services aren't inject to controller constructor.

It's there any way how I can use controllers as a service with DI and @Route annotation together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just add `@Route` annotation to your controller with a `service` parameter:

```
/** @Route("/", service="your.controller.service.id") */
class YourController
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this per action, or does it have to be the entire controller?

Comment: yeah. you can add per action `@Route`, but the entire controller also should be annotated with `service` parameter